# Long-running pipeline of events

Tags: pipe

I can't get this working on macOS:

```
unbuffer fswatch . | unbuffer xargs echo
```

What am I doing wrong? `fswatch` is like `inotifywait` on other systems.

Comment: `xargs` is probably waiting for enough input get maximum args for `echo`. Try with `xarg -L1` or `xargs -n1`

Comment: @muru Yep, thanks! xargs does its own buffering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`xargs`'s internal buffering caused that. This works:

```
unbuffer fswatch . | xargs -L1 echo "a change:"
```

or with `stdbuf`:

```
stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 fswatch . | xargs -L1 echo "a change:"
```